# pandas: ignore exception in lambda

Tags: python, pandas, exception, lambda

I have this Data Frame that consists of pdf URLs

```
                                              Source
0  http://www.ampire.com.tw/en/download.asp?fileN...
1  http://www.ampire.com.tw/en/download.asp?fileN...
2  http://www.buckeyeshapeform.com/media/1240/iso...
3  http://www.ionix-systems.com/files/EN91002009I...
4  http://php2.twinner.com.tw/files/chiplus/ISO90...
```

I created a function that converts these URLs into images and then OCR them and return certain line and i want that line to fill a new Column
that's what I do:

```
import cv2
import requests
import pdf2image
import pytesseract
import dateutil.parser as dparser
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def address(x):
    pdf = requests.get(x,stream=True)
    images = pdf2image.convert_from_bytes(pdf.raw.read())
    sora = 'sora.png'
    images[0].save(sora, 'PNG')
    img = cv2.imread(sora, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    #img = cv2.blur(img, (5, 5))

    #HSV (hue, saturation, value)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
    cv2.imwrite('temp.png',v)
    p = pytesseract.image_to_string(cv2.imread('temp.png'))
    for line in p.lower().split('\n'):
        if ':20' in line and ('iso' in line or 'iatf' in line or '1so' in line):
            return(line.title())
        elif ': 20' in line and ('iso' in line or 'iatf' in line or '1so' in line):
            return(line.title())
```

i want to run something with lambda that if the URL is Down or Doesn't contain a pdf or any error like that it just type "Down" in the "B" Column, something looks like this

```
df['B'] = df['Source'].apply(lambda x: "Down" if Exception else address(x))
```

what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Why not just return `"Down"` from your function? Look into `try-except` blocks.

Comment: the exception raises at the line     `images = pdf2image.convert_from_bytes(pdf.raw.read())` it doesn't proceed to the end, i tried making it in a form of try and except still got nothing I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Show what you tried

Comment: thanks for pointing out, when i went to read the function before i paste it I realized how idiot I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was doing it wrong, i tried adding try and except in an idiotic way

```
def address2(x):
    for link in x:
        try:
            pdf = requests.get(link,stream=True)
            images = pdf2image.convert_from_bytes(pdf.raw.read())
            sora = 'sora.png'
            images[0].save(sora, 'PNG')
            img = cv2.imread(sora, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            #img = cv2.blur(img, (5, 5))
            #HSV (hue, saturation, value)
            hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
            cv2.imwrite('temp.png',v)
            p = pytesseract.image_to_string(cv2.imread('temp.png'))
            for line in p.split('\n\n'):
                for country in pycountry.countries:
                    if country.name in line and('Quality' not in line) and ('Certificat' not in line):
                        return(line.title())
                    elif country.alpha_3 in line and('Quality' not in line) and ('Certificat' not in line):
                        return(line.title())
        except:
            return("Down")
```

but i fixed it to:

```
import cv2
import requests
import pdf2image
import pytesseract
import dateutil.parser as dparser
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def address(x):
    try:
        pdf = requests.get(x,stream=True)
        images = pdf2image.convert_from_bytes(pdf.raw.read())
        sora = 'sora.png'
        images[0].save(sora, 'PNG')
        img = cv2.imread(sora, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        #img = cv2.blur(img, (5, 5))

        #HSV (hue, saturation, value)
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
        cv2.imwrite('temp.png',v)
        p = pytesseract.image_to_string(cv2.imread('temp.png'))
        for line in p.lower().split('\n'):
            if ':20' in line and ('iso' in line or 'iatf' in line or '1so' in line):
                return(line.title())
            elif ': 20' in line and ('iso' in line or 'iatf' in line or '1so' in line):
                return(line.title())
    except:
        return("Down")
```

and it's now fine

Comment: You should try to avoid using such a general `except:` block. Instead, only catch the exception you expect, such as `except: TheRelevantExceptionType`. This is because, if anything else fails in your `try`-block of 10+ lines, you might not notice it, since your very general `except` swallows it. This could lead to very unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the response from your `requests.get()`, and return `Down` if the response is not as expected. It could look like:

```
import cv2
import requests
import pdf2image
import pytesseract
import dateutil.parser as dparser
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def address(x):
    pdf = requests.get(x,stream=True)
    if pdf.status_code != 200: # You could be even more specific here
        return "Down"
    else:
        images = pdf2image.convert_from_bytes(pdf.raw.read())
        sora = 'sora.png'
        images[0].save(sora, 'PNG')
        img = cv2.imread(sora, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        #img = cv2.blur(img, (5, 5))

        #HSV (hue, saturation, value)
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
        cv2.imwrite('temp.png',v)
        p = pytesseract.image_to_string(cv2.imread('temp.png'))
        for line in p.lower().split('\n'):
            if ':20' in line and ('iso' in line or 'iatf' in line or '1so' in line):
                return(line.title())
            elif ': 20' in line and ('iso' in line or 'iatf' in line or '1so' in line):
                return(line.title())
```